# Is there a way to receive envelope status via Docusign connect for each individual signing?

Tags: api, docusignapi, webhooks

I am aware of the fact that when all the parties available in the signing ceremony signs the document then webhook can post the data to the URL but I want webhook to post the data for each individual signing the envelope. In my case two participants are involved in the signing process and first person is doing the embedded signing. So when first person completes the signing process i want to update the stage. Please suggest me a way if i can do this via Docusign connect or is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Connect configuration, whether at Account-level (Web App "Settings") or Envelope-level (eventNotifcation in REST API), register for Recipient Events rather than or in addition to Envelope Events.  In your case, that would be Recipient Completed.
Connect will then be triggered by the signer finishing their signing.  The Connect message payload will still be the entire structure, but you will notice the change in Status under the particular signer's RecipientStatus.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two different ways: specify a connect configuration at the account level or at the envelope level.

If you would like to specify it at the account level, you have to configure a [custom connect configuration](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm) and select the events that you would like your listener to be notified of, including recipient events such as Delivered, Signed/Completed, Declined, etc.

If you would like to specify this at the envelope level, it will need to be done for each envelope sent, but you can specify the details of the listener along with other parameters in your envelope, the complete list can be found in the [createEnvelope reference here under recipientEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked all these docs but i have not found any listener for a case when the envelope is signed by only a single individual.